# Area of an irregular, n-sided, non-intersecting (edges) polygon algorithm

Tags: algorithms, polygons

I need to generate an irregular, n-sided polygon of non-intersecting edges (n= 200, for example) with the smallest area possible. The position of the vertex is random and I've tried designing a couple of algorithms with no satisfying result. Is there something out there with this specifications or a way of designing it? I have OpenGL if it helps.

Comment: What is the condition on the side lengths?

Comment: You receive the vertices, so it depends on it.

Answer (score 2):

Given a set of $n$ points in the plane, the problem of finding a minimum area convex $k$-gon among the points was considered by Eppstein, Overmars, Rote, and Woeginger in this [paper](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~eppstein/pubs/EppOveRot-DCG-92.pdf).  They give an algorithm that runs in time $O(kn^3)$.

As Gerry Myerson mentions, there is also the variant where we do not require the $k$-gon to be convex. Both these problems can be solved in time $O(kn^k)$ by checking all $k$-tuples of points.  However, this [paper](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~eppstein/pubs/Epp-TR-91-59.pdf) by Eppstein claims that no faster algorithm is known (see the Introduction) for the non-convex version.

Comment: OP doesn't use the word, "convex", so I'm not sure this is what's wanted. It may be one is required to have on the boundary all of the $n$ points given.

Comment: @GerryMyerson That's true.  The wording of the question was a bit vague, so I took my best guess at what it meant.  I guess we will have to wait until the OP clarifies.